# How to scale a view horizontally in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to be able to scale a view horizontally by dragging a circle to left or right. Like most of the editing apps.

Current solution doesn't scale the view properly

```
struct ScaleableView: View {
    
    @State private var frame: CGSize = .init(width: 500, height: 500)
    @State private var position: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Background
            Rectangle()
                .border(Color.gray, width: 3)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                .position(x: frame.width, y: frame.height / 2)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            let translationX = gesture.translation.width * 0.07
                            if gesture.translation.width > 0 {
                                frame.width += abs(translationX)
                                position.x += abs(translationX)
                            } else {
                                frame.width -= abs(translationX)
                                position.x -= abs(translationX)
                            }
                        }
                )
        }
        .position(position)
        .frame(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You must apply the gesture translation to the original position/frame before the gesture = save the frame/position at gesture start. BTW, your test on sign of translation is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code draws a rectangle outside the screen.

I am not sure what you intend to do. Check the below code if it helps and work around.

```
struct ScaleableView: View {
    @State private var frame: CGSize = .init(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2, height: 500)

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            // Background
            Rectangle()
                .border(Color.gray, width: 3)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: frame.width, height: frame.height)

            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .frame(width: 15, height: 15)
                .position(x: frame.width - 1.5, y: frame.height / 2)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .local)
                        .onChanged { gesture in
                            print(gesture.location.x)
                            frame.width = gesture.location.x
                        }
                )
        }
    }
}
```